# How to determine which dlls a lib "references"?

Tags: c++, powershell, dll

I have a C++ project that references a lib, which references a dll. In my case I want to create a setup package that includes all necessary files (e.g. assemblies etc.) and hence I need this referenced assemblies to be included in the setup package as well.

Is there a way to know which assemblies a lib references? I do execute a PowerShell that has access to and reads the project file in order to identify all necessary files, but this in-direct referenced assembly is not listed somewhere in the project file itself.

*Disclaimer*: I'm not an expert by any means when it comes to native C++ projects

Comment: For .NET, use the [Fuslogvw.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) tool to *"diagnose why the .NET Framework cannot locate an assembly at run time"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SDK tool "dumpbin" has various options to assist as well;

- `dumpbin /imports`
- Or via the linker `link /dump /imports`

If you are building the lib into a project, once compiled you can use "Dependency Walker" to view the dependencies. It is available from [its website](http://www.dependencywalker.com) and as part of the [Windows Driver Kit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547083.aspx); the versions may differ. *Note*; beware of the use on newer platforms, [as commented below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743995/how-to-know-which-dlls-a-lib-references/37744067?noredirect=1#comment62959422_37744067).

In general, the SDK utilities are the most up to date and correct for the targets you are using.

Comment: You can use `dumpbin /imports` on the compiled output too (or `link /dump /imports` - dumpbin and editbin are just wrappers for link)

Comment: It will work on a .lib but I can't find a good way of just getting the DLL name. `dumpbin /headers` will dump a structure per symbol import that contains the line "DLL name", but you'd need to pipe it through grep, sort, uniq to just get the one output I think.

Comment: @Rup, makes sense. Those tools are centred around the symbols and then where they come from (those load them as required at runtime). I think this is pretty much all that Dependency Walker does, it is just a nice GUI on top of the that whole underlying mechanism.

Comment: Dependency Walker hasn't been update in years. Today, it's virtually useless, and certainly **not** centered around the system-provided API's. Instead, it implements its very own parsers and binary lookup. Dumpbin produces way more reliable results.

Comment: @IInspectable. What types are dependencies does it fail to detect and list?

Comment: Anything to do with the Universal CRT, for example. And it's kind of flaky on the whole WoW64 resolution as well. In all, lots of false positives intermixed with lots of false negatives. Recommendation: Don't use.

Comment: Also note, that the latest version of dependency walker isn't even available through its official homepage ([Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)), but only available through the [Windows Driver Kit Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547083.aspx). I don't know how this version differs from the 'official' one, which additional features, or which bug fixes have been incorporated, or whether it's simply a re-branded version with only a higher version number assigned.